# Python code for image to string conversion

Tags: python-3.x

`NameError: name 'pytesseract' is not defined`

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string
img=Image.open('hlo.png')
text=pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
speech=gTTS(text=text,lang="en",slow=False) 
speech.save('hello.mp3')
```

Comment: the line text=pytesseract.image_to_string(img) should be text=image_to_string(img)

Comment: Where is the import for gTTS?